# Detecting enclosure voltage for batteries

Tags: relay, safety, leakage-current, metal

I have made an enclosure out of metal that is used to enclose my battery pack. I have stacked this enclosure with 18650 lithium batteries to build up a battery pack (24V).

Every time an error is picked up we have implemented a new process to this so that the error does not occur. But it has come to a point where we now need an electronic system.

**What I need:**

This electronic system will detect if the metal enclosure (chassis) has voltage present on it, either positive or negative, and sound a buzzer or send some form of signal to alert us.

**My solution:**

My idea wasa to connect up two relays has shown in the schematic below. One relay is used to detect positve voltage leakage and the other is used to ground. When either one is detected it closes the relay and then activates the siren/buzzer.

**My question:**

Is my idea correct, is there any issues with the idea and what alternatives are out there to achieve this outcome?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9S9CW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit recommended by Marla

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU59Lf.png)</sup>

**Edit 3:**

[image]

Comment: What do you need help with? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit is two relays in series across the battery. Current will flow at all times. Whether the relays will pull in is unknown.

If a short (error) is made, that will short out one of the relays, energizing fully the other relay.

Redraw your circuit with "battery chassis" connected and you will see the two relays coils are in series.

Possible solution :. Use 2 resistors, of high value, perhaps greater than 330k, to form resistor divider. The center of the resistor divider
connected to chassis. Now if voltage with respect to battery negative is 1/2 battery volts, all is well.
Build a comparator to monitor for zero or full battery volts to detect error.
Essentially replace your two relays with resistors and monitor the center volts of the divider.

**. Be aware that there will be leakage current. This leakage current is determined by your resistor value selection.

Comment: Thanks I see your point now, what do you suggest to do?

Comment: Arggh so basically connect the center of resistor divider to chassis and also feed it to a schmitt trigger?

Comment: Not Schmitt trigger. Use comparators.

Comment: You can choose the error level. For example, if volts greater than 20 volt then error. And if volts is less than 5 volts, then error.

Comment: I see thanks, Marla. I will simulate and update my post

Comment: When I simulate it (see edit 3), I am getting a current pull of 336A when positive chassis voltage is detected. Does this seem correct?

Comment: @JoeyB.   .   Place a resistor in series with pin3 on Opamp. Perhaps 22k ohms. Do the same with pin 2, resistor in series.

Comment: That was an oversight... :). So this method now means that there will be a constant voltage of 12V on the chassis under normal condidtions i.e. no short between battery and chassis, correct?

Comment: Yes, 12 volts with respect to board ground, in series with the resistors. Resistors are there to limit amount of current should someone make contact.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to test both cases simultanously?

If not, choose a siren working from 3 to 4.3V, and in reverse. Then just connect one side to the chasis, and the other one first to +, then to - : if chassis is connected somewhere, you get a sound.

If you want to automate it, you could make a small circuit (arduino + relay module for example) witching beween connexion to + or -

Comment: Well if both the positive and negative touch the enclosure simultaneously, then it's going to get very ugly and deadly.....

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your design is you are trying to use the battery *itself* as the voltage differential for leak detection.  As you have observed, that doesn't work if the voltage differential is zero!   **So use an external current source instead**.

After all, what you *really* want to test is whether current can get between the battery and its chassis. The voltage of the leak is not the issue.

Use an external current source.  (it needs to be **a current-limited source** because in a failing test, potentially unlimited current could flow).  *Attempt* to flow current from it, via a current detector, via the battery (either terminal not both) and the chassis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9kdri.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So what is happening here?   On the lower left, you have a good battery. The current source and the current detector are *attempting* to complete a circuit, but it's not working -- the battery insulation is good.

On the lower right, you have a failing battery, which has a non-infinity resistance between anywhere on the battery, and chassis.  As you can see, this is a complete loop and current will flow.

Of course, if the current-limited source had exactly the same voltage as the battery, they would block each other - like 2 of the same batteries wired in parallel (current doesn't normally flow between them).  *So you must choose a current source of presumably higher voltage in all cases than the battery under test*.

You keep the battery and source from fighting each other a) by limiting current, and b) by disconnecting immediately upon detecting a ground fault/failure.

The current-limited source's voltage needs to be high enough to do the job, but its current only needs to be as high as your "failure threshold". For instance if you fail at 1 milliamp current flow between battery and chassis, then the current source need only be 1 milliamp.  You would need to be able to measure that low, of course!

The classic example of such a current source is a "mega-ohm-meter". Which is the normal appliance used for this type of testing.  It provides the current source (of a usefully high test voltage) and current detector in one package.  Mega-ohm-meters typically use test voltages of 250, 500 or 1000 volts, which are appropriate insulation test voltages for motors and other AC mains equipment.

Comment: So basically add a shunt resistor and measure the current through it? But if the chassis is grounded and if If I place then place the probe on the negative of the battery then no current will flow hence this is a false reading, so this means I need two of these, where one probe is placed on each of the battery terminals

Comment: Edited.  No! You can't use the battery itself as the current source.  That doesn't work for the reason you've already found.  You need a current source, and really any current detector - I wouldn't think a shunt resistor would be detectable at low currents. Any current is a failure.

Comment: So what I need is a resistance measurement device. That I connect between chassis and battery?

Comment: @JoeyB yes exactly, but with two wrinkles: #1 it must use a high enough voltage to do an insulation test, which means it must disconnect immediately if leakage is detected, so it doesn't do something crazy to the battery.  And #2 it must survive receiving a voltage of (its own test voltage) + (battery voltage), while still detecting on (its own test voltage) - (battery voltage). Because you never know where the fault will be.

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by high enough voltage? Also can I just use a zener to create this voltage using the battery voltage (like a 9V zener). I'm just confused on how to practically do this and what components I need

Comment: @JoeyB What are you testing?  You are testing the insulation between battery and chassis.  What voltage do you want that insulation to withstand?  Does your engineering department have any numbers on that?   It's time to drop the idea of using the battery under test as the voltage source, as that leaves you unable to detect certain leakages. That was your OP question, remember?