# High-voltage chassis voltage detector using a comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

I am planning on using a comparator together with a resistor divider network to detect when a chassis voltage is present.

Please refer to the previous post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606396/detecting-enclosure-voltage-for-batteries) for more info if needed.

So S1 is used to simulate when a chassis voltage is present, however, the simulation is showing a current of 337 A.

I am using 80 V to test, so I used the OPA454 op-amp.

Why am I getting a current draw of 337 A?

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: You know, if you just want to detect whether a chassis voltage is present (and it sounds like the case since that's what you said and you using a comparator) you don't actually need an 80V comparator. You can use current limiting series resistors with diode clamps and use a much lower voltage run-of-the-mill comparator. You can even step down the voltage with a divider into the power rail range of your low-voltage comparator and then clamp it if it is too high.

Comment: @DKNguyen is there a reason for deleting your answer? Also thanks for the advice I have managed to come up with a simple circuit, see edit 2 in my post

Comment: Yeah, WhatRoughtBeast pointed out that it's 80V powering your op-amp. I kept looking at the 60Vdd on the inverting input. But what I said about R1/R2 and DC bias input currents is still true.  With regards to your new circuit, U1A if fine but U1B input needs clamping protection too from the 80V. Use a fast diode. Fast low voltage if possible like a Schottky.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes! protection for U1B as well, was only thinking that U1A was receiving the 80V hahaha, thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't know your use-case but is it possible for the chassis voltage to go negative? If so, you need clamping diodes to the low-side power rails as well.

Comment: @DKNguyen The chassis should only be ground or positive (80V), it should never be negative

Comment: Okay. You may share the clamp between both op amps, by the way. U1B could use R1 for its DC bias currents as well. Doesn't need to be pull up.

Comment: @DKNguyen also forget to add a series resistor for U1B pin 6 :(

Comment: (I consider the series resistor part of the clamp, along with the diode.)

Comment: @DKNguyen yes I added it along with the diode and not at pin6, I see my comment is a bit unclear on that