# Insulation testing of chassis leakage current/voltage (Megohmmeter)

Tags: resistance, leakage-current

Previous [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606396/detecting-enclosure-voltage-for-batteries/606473?noredirect=1#comment1597616_606473)

I feel my original post was not asked in a correct manner. I previously said I wanted to detect voltage but it now appears I should be detecting current instead.

My setup still remains the same as below. However, a 80V battery pack is now used.

I have made an enclosure out of metal that is used to enclose my battery pack. I have stacked this enclosure with 18650 lithium batteries to build up a battery pack (80V).

Every time an error is picked up we have implemented a new process to this so that the error does not occur. But it has come to a point where we now need an electronic system.

**What I need:**

This electronic system will detect if the metal enclosure (chassis) has current flowing through it. If the current is detected on the chassis (> 20mA), then a circuit will output a 5V output signal. Hence 0V output signal means no leakage detected.

**My question:**

From the previous post a user pointed out using a megohmmeter, however, how do I design one that will achieve what I need and also output a 5V signal if leakage is detected?

Comment: "*This electronic system will detect if the metal enclosure (chassis) has current **flowing through it**.*" Through it to where? Current doesn't flow unless there is a circuit and a potential difference.

Comment: @Transistor yes current does not flow unless there is a closed loop, hence I used the word "detect", current will flow when the electronic system "detects"

Comment: "*I feel my original post was not asked in a correct manner.*" You should probably edit the original post to fix it. Leave enough of the original there so that the existing answers don't look stupid. Then delete this question.

Comment: So the battery pack is supposed to be isolated from the metal case and you just want to detect if one pole of it has made contact with the case? If one pole makes contact you still won't have current flow but a circuit could be designed to detect the **voltage** produced. It will require a reference connection to the battery.

Comment: @Transistor those answers are correct if the voltage was the detection parameter, however I realised I need current, hence a new post is more relevant

Comment: @Transistor "So the battery pack is supposed to be isolated" yes you are correct, By pole, I assume the positive or negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: @Transistor "The problem with your design is you are trying to use the battery itself as the voltage differential for leak detection. As you have observed, that doesn't work if the voltage differential is zero! So use an external current source instead."

Comment: If the metal case is isolated from battery, it has no connection to it at all, and if any part of battery accidentally makes contact with the metal case, then it has one connection, so there is no loop, so there will be no current flowing, so you can't detect current.

Comment: @Justme the chassis will either become positively charged or negatively charged. So the chassis is already electrostaticly charged. And either positive charge will flow from the battery or negative.